# LC-3 Program is returning something that cannot be printed

Tags: lc3

I wrote a program for LC-3 to take in a number under 10 until 0 is reached, and then output the largest number entered.

Everything seems to work but I keep getting an incorrect, or nonexistent result. For example, if I input 1, 2, 3, then 0, it should say:

> Zero entered, ending program. The largest integer entered was 3

but I'm getting nothing back.

The method I'm attempting to use to output the largest integer is to use the two's complement system to determine the larger number of two, and loop back if 0 is not entered, but I think my logic has a major issue.

Sorry, the formatting might be a bit wonky, and if you need any more information or if I've done something wrong (in terms of the post - I know my code is wrong) please let me know.

Thank you in advance! (Also I have a sample output at the bottom of the code.)

```
    .ORIG   x3000

    AND     R0,R0,#0        ;clear R0
    AND     R0,R0,#0        ;clear R1
    LEA         R0, MSG1        ;load address of message 1
    PUTS                    ;display message

    GETC                    ;read in character from keyboard
    OUT                 ;echo input
    ST      R0, NUM1        ;store the number in num1
    LD      R2, NUM1
    LD      R1, POS48
    ADD     R2,R2, R1       ;adds 48 to make the character a number
    BRz     ZERO            ;checks if the number is zero

    LD      R0, NEWLINE     ;load newline
    OUT                 ;execute newline

    LOOP    LEA         R0, MSG1        ;load address of message 1
    PUTS                    ;display message

    GETC                    ;read in character from keyboard
    OUT                 ;echo input
    ST      R0, NUM2        ;store character in num2
    LD      R2, POS48
    LD      R3, NUM2
    ADD     R0, R3, R2      ;adds 48 to make the character a number
    BRz     ZERO            ;checks if the number is zero

    LD      R0, NEWLINE     ;load newline
    OUT                 ;execute newline

    LD      R1, NUM1        ;load the first number
    LD      R2, NUM2        ;load the second number
    NOT     R2, R2          ;two's complement of R2
    ADD     R2, R2, #1      ;getting negative of num 2
    ADD     R0, R1, R2      ;adding the two values
    ST      R0, MAX         ;storing larger number in NUM5


    BRnz        LOOP            ;Branch if R0 is positive

    ZERO    LEA     R0, MSG2        ;load message if number entred is zero
    PUTS                    ;display message
    LD      R0, NEWLINE     ;load newline
    OUT                 ;execute newline
    LEA     R0, MSG3        ;load largest int message
    PUTS                    ;display

    LD      R2, MAX
    LD      R1, POS48
    ADD     R1, R2, R1      ;adds 48 to make the character a number
    LD      R0, MAX         ;load largest int
    OUT                 ;display largest int
    HALT                    ;end program

    ;*** Data ***
    MSG1        .STRINGZ    "Enter a single-digit integer: "
    MSG2        .STRINGZ    "Zero entered, ending program."
    MSG3        .STRINGZ    "The largest integer is: "
    POS48       .FILL       #48
    NEWLINE     .FILL       #10
    NUM1        .BLKW       1
    NUM2        .BLKW       1
    MAX         .BLKW       1

    .END
```

Sample output - 
Enter a single-digit integer: 1
Enter a single-digit integer: 2
Enter a single-digit integer: 3
Enter a single-digit integer: 0
Zero entered, ending program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After debugging your program I was able to find two logical bugs in your code. The first is when you were trying to convert between integer value and ascii value. The second is when you are comparing two numbers to find which is larger. I have re-created a working version of your program and commented it very thoroughly so it should be easy to follow along with.

---

First problem was with your ascii integer conversion code. You were trying to convert to an integer value from an ascii digit using POS48 which was equal to 48; however, in order to convert from ascii to integer you must subract 48, or in the case of assembly add -48. Then to convert back from an integer value to an ascii value you would add positive 48.

For Example:

```
NEG48   .FILL    xFFD0    ;create constant NEG48 which = xFFD0 = -48
LD      R6, NEG48         ;load NEG48 into register 6
GETC                      ;get user input
ADD     R0, R0, R6        ;add -48 to the user input to get integer value
```

---

The second problem was with the code comparing two integer values to find which is larger. In your code you were getting the two's compliment, getting the negative of the second value, and then adding it to the first value. This is correct except that you need to use a BRn and BRp to evaluate whether the result is positive or negative. If the value is positive this means that the first number is larger, and if it's negative the second number is larger. BRn will branch is negative, and BRp will branch if positive.

For Example the following code will compare a new number inputted by the user earlier in your program to the current maximum value entered by the user then saves the larger value into the CURRENTMAX variable:

```
LD  R2, CURRENTMAX  ;load CURRENTMAX
LD  R3, NEWNUM      ;load NEWNUM
NOT R4, R3          ;two's complement of NEWNUM
ADD R4, R4, #1      ;getting negative of NEWNUM
ADD R1, R4, R2      ;adding the negative of NEWNUM to CURRENTMAX
BRn LrgR3           ;if the result in R1 is negative NEWNUM is larger so branch to LrgR3
BRp LrgR2           ;if the result in R1 is positive CURRENTMAX is larger so branch to LrgR2

;**************** LrgR3 ****************
LrgR3               ;begin LrgR3
ST  R3, CURRENTMAX  ;store the larger result in CURRENTMAX
BR  LOOP            ;branch to LOOP

;**************** LrgR2 ****************
LrgR2               ;begin LrgR2
ST  R2, CURRENTMAX  ;store the larger result in CURRENTMAX
BR  LOOP            ;branch to LOOP
```

---

Finally here is the working re-written version that I made to help you better solve this problem.

```
.ORIG   x3000

;**************** POLL INITIAL USER INPUT ****************
LD  R5, POS48       ;load num to char conversion value
LD  R6, NEG48       ;load char to num conversion value

LEA R0, MSG1        ;load MSG1
PUTS                ;display MSG1
GETC                ;get user input
OUT                 ;display users input

ADD R0, R0, R6      ;convert input char into a number value
ST  R0, CURRENTMAX  ;store numer value into MAX since the only number entered is obviously the MAX value entered
BRz ZERO            ;if zero branch to ZERO

LD  R0, NEWLINE     ;load newline
OUT                 ;display newline

;**************** LOOP ****************
LOOP                ;begin LOOP
LEA R0, MSG1        ;load MSG1
PUTS                ;display MSG1
GETC                ;get under input
OUT                 ;display user input

ADD R0, R0, R6      ;convert user input char into a number value
ST  R0, NEWNUM      ;store number value into NEWNUM
BRz ZERO            ;if zero branch to ZERO

LD  R0, NEWLINE     ;load newline
OUT                 ;display newline

LD  R2, CURRENTMAX  ;load CURRENTMAX
LD  R3, NEWNUM      ;load NEWNUM
NOT R4, R3          ;two's complement of NEWNUM
ADD R4, R4, #1      ;getting negative of NEWNUM
ADD R1, R4, R2      ;adding the negative of NEWNUM to CURRENTMAX
BRn LrgR3           ;if the result in R1 is negative NEWNUM is larger so branch to LrgR3
BRp LrgR2           ;if the result in R1 is positive CURRENTMAX is larger so branch to LrgR2

;**************** LrgR3 ****************
LrgR3               ;begin LrgR3
ST  R3, CURRENTMAX  ;store the larger result in CURRENTMAX
BR  LOOP            ;branch to LOOP

;**************** LrgR2 ****************
LrgR2               ;begin LrgR2
ST  R2, CURRENTMAX  ;store the larger result in CURRENTMAX
BR  LOOP            ;branch to LOOP

;**************** ZERO ****************
ZERO                ;begin ZERO
LD  R0, NEWLINE     ;load newline
OUT                 ;display newline
LEA R0, MSG2        ;load MSG2
PUTS                ;display MSG2
LD  R0, NEWLINE     ;load newline
OUT                 ;display newline
LEA R0, MSG3        ;load MSG3
PUTS                ;display MSG3

LD  R0, CURRENTMAX  ;load CURRENTMAXvalue
ADD R0, R0, R5      ;convert CURRENTMAX num into char
OUT                 ;display CURRENTMAX's char value
HALT                ;end program


;**************** Variables and Constants ****************
MSG1        .STRINGZ    "Enter a single-digit integer: "
MSG2        .STRINGZ    "Zero entered, ending program."
MSG3        .STRINGZ    "The largest integer is: "
POS48       .FILL       x30
NEG48       .FILL       xFFD0
NEWLINE     .FILL       #10
NEWNUM      .BLKW       1
CURRENTMAX  .BLKW       1

.END
```